# RDBMS: what is the best way to perform several operations

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, transactions, rdbms

I use PostgreSQL 8.4, but i think my question can be expanded to most of the RDBMS.

I need to perform data-changing operation like update or delete for those rows, where the specified column has value from the specified set. For example I want to delete those rows, where id is in (1,4,7,8).

The whole operation should either succeed or fail, so I have two options here:

- Use `IN` syntax, like

`DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id IN (1,4,7,8)`

- Use several single operations executed within one transaction, like

`DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = 1;`

`DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = 4;`

`...`

Is there any difference between these two approaches when executed as plain SQL commands? Which one is better?

The same questions when using JDBC prepared statements for these operations?

Comment: the best way to see what is the difference is to use `EXPLAIN` to see how the planner executes first query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use transactions, in my opinion. With the several-operation approach you will have many more round trips across the network. There may also be a difference in what indexes get used, so check out the query plan.

Comment: thanks, but both approaches run in a single transaction, and I'm asking for a difference between them

Comment: ok, got the reason about network argument. Will check the query plan

Answer (score 0):

So I checked `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and PostgreSQL uses special filter for `IN (...)` request when traversing the table. So the major difference should be in performance: with `IN (...)` you traverse the table one time. With N separate requests `= ?` you traverse table N times. Though PostgreSQL should optimize this so it's actually faster, but still must be slower that `IN (...)`